# LINQ to SQL and Self Related Table

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, orm

We have the following test model in the dbml file:

[Model http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a86582498a.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a86582498a.gif)

For the test case there are 4 records in the table, 1 parent, 3 children.  We are looking for the siblings of a specific record, including the specific record.

```
using (var db = new TestDataContext())
{
    var query = 
        from f in db.Foos
        where f.Name == "Two"
        select f.Foo1.Foos;              // get the record's parent's children

    var foos = query.SelectMany(f => f); // project the EntitySet

    Assert.AreEqual(3, foos.Count());    // passes
}
```

This returns the correct items with the following SQL:

```
SELECT     [t2].[FooId], 
           [t2].[ParentFooId], 
           [t2].[Name]
FROM       [dbo].[Foos] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Foos] AS [t1] ON [t1].[FooId] = [t0].[ParentFooId]
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[Foos] AS [t2]
WHERE      ([t0].[Name] = @p0) 
AND        ([t2].[ParentFooId] = [t1].[FooId])
```

We are wondering about the CROSS JOIN, this apparently is the result of the SelectMany?
Is there another way we should approach this in order to not have the CROSS JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

You can stack from statements in a Linq query and that will probably help you out here.

```
var query = from f in db.Foos
            from f2 in f.Foos
            where f.Name == "Two"
            select f2;
```

Which produces.

```
SELECT [t1].[FooId],
       [t1].[Name],
       [t1].[ParentFooId]
FROM [dbo].[Foos] AS [t0], [dbo].[Foos] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t0].[Name] = @p0) AND ([t1].[ParentFooId] = [t0].[FooId])
```

Comment: So this is going to leave the type of join up to SQL Server since one isn't specified?

Comment: Yes. By default, that's an inner join.

Comment: It was my understanding that ',' will leave determining the join up to SQL Server; it may be an inner join or it may be a cross join.  If not a reference to that implementation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively do:

```
var query = from f in db.Foos
            where (from fo in db.Foos
                   where fo.Name == "Two"
                   select fo.ParentId).Contains(f.ParentId)
            select f;
```

This should result in something like:

```
SELECT     [t1].[FooId], 
           [t1].[ParentFooId], 
           [t1].[Name]
FROM       [dbo].[Foos] AS [t1]
WHERE      [t1].[ParentFooId] IN (SELECT [t0].[ParentFooId]
                                  FROM [dbo].[Foos] AS [t0]
                                  WHERE[t0].[Name] = @p0)
```

May differ a bit (possibly an `Exists()`depending on your model)...I don't have a profiler window handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var siblings = DataContext.Foos.Where(a => a.FooID == 3)
    .Select(b => Foos.Where(b => Foos.ParentFooID == a.ParentFooID));

Assert.AreEqual(3, siblings.Count());
```

Comment: you are missing a closing brace!